# SetInterval Timeout - Variable Structure reset timeout

Tags: javascript, html, slider, setinterval, clearinterval

I am setting a timeout to reset the timeout interval on a click event on a simple Javascript coded slider.

The slider can be found at:

http://rastastation.com/rastaradio.html

The code appears as follows in the  section:

---

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
      function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById("img").src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);
          window.clearInterval(this.image);

      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);
          window.clearInterval(this.image);           

      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 9000);
      }


      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "images/carousel_anthonyb2.png";
      images[1] = "images/carousel_capleton2.png";
      images[2] = "images/carousel_sizzla2.png";
      images[3] = "images/carousel_earlsixteen.png";
      images[4] = "images/carousel_norrisreid.png";
      images[5] = "images/carousel_yamibolo2.png";
      images[6] = "images/carousel_fantanmojah2.png";
      images[7] = "images/carousel_natural_black2.png";
      images[8] = "images/carousel_admiraltibet.png";
      images[9] = "images/carousel_luciano.png"; 
  </script>
```

---

I need the click event to reset the timeout and particularly set the Internal Variable.

As shown by W3Schools, it appears as follows:

---

```
window.clearInterval(intervalVariable)
```

---

How would I easily go about doing this.

The slider works and I am adding advanced functionality.  This is where I am after 30 minutes of customizing it.

Tag as follows:

```
<div id="rgStateSLIDER">
<img id="img" src="images/carousel_start.png">
<div id="containerSliderControls">
<div class="buttonPrevious" onclick="displayPreviousImage()"></div>
<div class="buttonNext" onclick="displayNextImage()"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks...William

UI Developer - Basis Interactive Inc.

Comment: The assignment `x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1` can be `x = ++x % images.length`.

Comment: Please outline this in more details.  I see a syntax error when implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, it may help you solving your problem.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
      function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById("img").src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;

         clearInterval(timer);
         displayImage(images[x]);
         timer = setInterval( displayThisImage, 5000 );
      }

      function displayThisImage( ) {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1; 
          displayImage(images[x]);
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
         clearInterval(timer);
         displayImage(images[x]);
         timer = setInterval( displayThisImage, 5000 );
      }

      function startTimer() {
         timer =    setInterval( displayThisImage, 5000 );
      }


      var images = [], x = -1;
      var timer ;
      images[0] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_anthonyb2.png";
      images[1] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_capleton2.png";
      images[2] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_sizzla2.png";
      images[3] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_earlsixteen.png";
      images[4] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_norrisreid.png";
      images[5] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_yamibolo2.png";
      images[6] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_fantanmojah2.png";
      images[7] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_natural_black2.png";
      images[8] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_admiraltibet.png";
      images[9] = "http://rastastation.com/images/carousel_luciano.png"; 
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Aziz.  This is good work as always.  Let us develop the Islamic Wordpress Knowledge Base as planned

Answer (score 0):

The "Internal Variable" (I think you mean interval variable) is returned by the call to *setTimeout*:

```
function startTimer() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 9000);
}
```

but you don't assign it to anything, so it's lost. Given your current design, you should create a global called (say) *timerInterval*. Then have a new function *clearTimer*:

```
function clearTimer() {

    // Only clear it if it's been set
    if (timerInterval) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        timerInterval = null;
    }
}
```

And in any function that sets the interval, make sure you clear it first (otherwise you'll start multiple timers):

```
function startTimer() {

    // Make sure there's no timer running
    clearTimer();

    // Keep the value
    timerInterval = setInterval(displayNextImage, 9000);
}
```

And in the other functions, re–use the *startTimer* function:

```
  function displayNextImage() {
      x = ++x % 12;
      displayImage(images[x]);
      startTimer();
  }
```

and do the same for the other functions, e.g.

```
function displayPreviousImage() {
    x = (x || images.length) - 1;
    displayImage(images[x]);
    startTimer();
}
```

Untested, but you should get the idea.

You should look to contain the global variables in closures so that they remain private, particularly when you are using names that are easily confused with other variables and properties (e.g. document.images).

Comment: I will test it out.  Thanks for the advice.  The other solution noted above worked, with one issue - it deactivated autoplay.  however, the code is clear and simple.  Your solution is more ideal in that it uses global variables, notwithstanding its untested as of yet.  It appears your solution needs some refinement in the context of this Slider application.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code i used your code for sample

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  var timer = null;

  function displayImage(image) {
      document.getElementById("img").src = image;
  }

  function displayNextImage() {
      x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
      displayImage(images[x]);
      // window.clearInterval(this.image); // old code
      window.clearInterval(timer); // new code       
  }

  function displayPreviousImage() {
      x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
      displayImage(images[x]);
      // window.clearInterval(this.image); // old code
      window.clearInterval(timer); // new code        

  }

  function startTimer() {
      timer = setInterval(displayNextImage, 9000);
  }

  function stopTimer() {
      clearInterval(timer);
  }


  var images = [], x = -1;
  images[0] = "images/carousel_anthonyb2.png";
  images[1] = "images/carousel_capleton2.png";
  images[2] = "images/carousel_sizzla2.png";
  images[3] = "images/carousel_earlsixteen.png";
  images[4] = "images/carousel_norrisreid.png";
  images[5] = "images/carousel_yamibolo2.png";
  images[6] = "images/carousel_fantanmojah2.png";
  images[7] = "images/carousel_natural_black2.png";
  images[8] = "images/carousel_admiraltibet.png";
  images[9] = "images/carousel_luciano.png";
```

Comment: In the context of my code, what is the Internal Variable?

Comment: I edited the code above. just check the difference with your code.

Comment: That worked.  Nonetheless, it deactivated the autoplay.  I will fix that next.  I am turning this into an admin managed Slider with the ability to link the artist song playing to the thumbnail in the slider.  What are your thoughts on that.

Comment: It would be cool to add that functionality but make the picture close to the player so it would be noticeable. It's just my opinion though.

Comment: I am making it work similar to a WP Plugin I use that styles post data with a thumbnail adjacent to the text.  However, I do agree with that concept as I am building a JS player that will add a small thumb next to the artists on the player.  Thanks for the help.  What is an easy method to activate the auto play on click on a small prompt in the bottom right of the slider.